# Two actions with one button android

Tags: android, button, android-activity, action

I have this problem, that i want to start an activity on a button click. That i have done, but when i start the new activity, I also want to stop the vibrator at the same time, so that when the old activity goes onPause i want the vibrator to stop. The code i have:

```
package com.edae;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Btcom extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 private Button bokay;
 Vibrator vibe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_btcom);
    bokay = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.okay);
    bokay.setOnClickListener(this);
    final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    int dot = 2000;
    long patten[] = {0, dot };
    vibe.vibrate(patten, -1);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent openBoot = new Intent(this, Boot.class);
    startActivity(openBoot);
    super.onPause();
  }
}
```

Comment: Override  `onPause()` method and stop the vibrator there, also, is not necessary to call `onPause()` in `onClick()` method.

Comment: Ahh of cause.. that's obvious.. sorry for wasting you're and others time.. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small fault in your code. You have redeclared `vibe` in your `onCreate`.
First replace

```
final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

with

```
vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

and declare your global variable `vibe` `final` .

Then you can solve your problem like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent openBoot = new Intent(this, Boot.class);
    vibe.cancel();
    startActivity(openBoot);
  }
}
```

The `super.onPause()` isn't needed here, because `startActivity(openBoot)` automatically pauses your activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v){
Intent openBoot = new Intent(this, Boot.class);
startActivity(openBoot);
//stop your vibrator here.
super.onPause();
```